# using BS4 on fields that contain the escape character in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So my content I'm scraping has the escape character in the class name.

Here's what the data looks like.

```
<div class='\"content-review\"'> blah blah blah </div>
```

I've tried doing this:

```
mydivs = soup.findAll("div", {"class": repr('\"content-review\"')})
```

and it returns an empty array. I think this has a simple solution but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: is the content dynamically loaded and therefore a method like selenium needed?

Answer (score 0):

The escape characters may not be your problem. I believe "class" is a reserved word in Python, so you can't use it as a keyword argument. Beautiful Soup [handles this](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class) by using the keyword argument "class_" instead. Try something like this":

```
mydivs = soup.findAll("div", class_="content-review")
```

If that still doesn't work, then you can tell Beautiful Soup to ignore the escaped quotes like so:

```
import re
mydivs = soup.findAll("div", class_=re.compile("content-review"))
```

Comment: tried that, and tried it with class_=repr('\"content-review\"'). still empty. hmmm

Comment: You are correct class is a reserved word, but the way OP has it, is an acceptable syntax as a dictionary {“class”:”string”}. I like your solution with regex. That should work. If not, might be dealing with a dynamic site.

Comment: I'm also viewing the html text before the soup outputs, the div class I need is definitely there

Comment: So the div class is definitely in the html response you get? Viewing the html response through the response and html from the browser’s response could be different if the page is dynamic.

Comment: If the page/data is rendered after the page is accessed, you won’t find the same tags/content in the html that is initially pulled. You’d have to use something like selenium to allow the page to render, and then grab the source html. The data could also be within a json structure sometimes as well within the html. Do you mind sharing the url, and a specific text/content you’re wanting to parse?

Answer (score 0):

I added one more backslash alongside existing escape characters and it worked for me.

```
soup.find_all("div", {"class": '\\"content-review\\"'})
```

I'm not quite sure why but it is what it returned when I tried getting the content of "class" label. Maybe it means escaping the escape character.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with escape characters appearing in class that I was querying. I used the following method to query these tags:

```
soup.find_all(name='div', attrs={'class': 'content-review'})
```